# Alternative to Server class for executing an sql script

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am currently using:

namespace KezberProjectManager
{

```
    public partial class VisitClear : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=JOSH-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KezBlu;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(
    HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, 
    @"App_Data\kb.sql"));

            string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);

        }
    }
}
```

to execute a script.

Locally this runs great because I reference the smo dll among others. These are not on the Goaddy server I use so this code will not run on the server.

Is there a way to execute sql files with only .Net 4 assembly references?

I do not know how else GoDaddy expects me to create tables.....

Thanks

```
USE [KezBlu]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Customer_Case]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] DROP CONSTRAINT [Customer_Case]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Case]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Case]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Status_Case]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] DROP CONSTRAINT [Status_Case]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Group_Employee]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] DROP CONSTRAINT [Group_Employee]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Employee_EmployeGroupFilter]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters] DROP CONSTRAINT [Employee_EmployeGroupFilter]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Group_EmployeGroupFilter]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters] DROP CONSTRAINT [Group_EmployeGroupFilter]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Employee_LockedDate]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LockedDates] DROP CONSTRAINT [Employee_LockedDate]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Project]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Project]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Employee_Schedule]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] DROP CONSTRAINT [Employee_Schedule]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Recurring_Schedule]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] DROP CONSTRAINT [Recurring_Schedule]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Project_Task]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] DROP CONSTRAINT [Project_Task]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Task]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Task1]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task1]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Task]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] DROP CONSTRAINT [Project_Task]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task1]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Task]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Cases]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] DROP CONSTRAINT [Customer_Case]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Case]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] DROP CONSTRAINT [Status_Case]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Cases]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Project]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Project]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Project]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters] DROP CONSTRAINT [Employee_EmployeGroupFilter]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters] DROP CONSTRAINT [Group_EmployeGroupFilter]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[LockedDates]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LockedDates] DROP CONSTRAINT [Employee_LockedDate]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[LockedDates]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Schedule]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] DROP CONSTRAINT [Employee_Schedule]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] DROP CONSTRAINT [Recurring_Schedule]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Schedule]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Employee]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] DROP CONSTRAINT [Group_Employee]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Colors]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Colors]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Customers]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Customers]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Group]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Group]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Recurring]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Recurring]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Settings]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Settings]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Statuses]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Statuses]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Statuses]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Statuses](
    [StatusID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StatusDescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Statuses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StatusID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Settings]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Settings](
    [SettingID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SettingKey] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SettingValue] [text] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Settings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SettingID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Recurring]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Recurring](
    [RecurringID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Period] [int] NULL,
    [DateStart] [datetime] NULL,
    [DateLast] [datetime] NULL,
    [Advance] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Recurring] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RecurringID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Group]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group](
    [GroupID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GroupDescription] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [IsReadOnly] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.[Group]]] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GroupID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Customers]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerDescription] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Colors]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Colors](
    [ColorID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ColorValue] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Colors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ColorID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Employee]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [EmployeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeEmail] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EmployePassword] [char](44) NOT NULL,
    [DefaultNumWeek] [smallint] NULL,
    [GroupID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Schedule]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schedule](
    [ScheduleID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateFrom] [datetime] NULL,
    [Hours] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [EmployeID] [int] NULL,
    [RecurringID] [int] NULL,
    [Priority] [int] NULL,
    [DateTo] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsLocked] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [BumpPriority] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Schedule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ScheduleID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[LockedDates]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LockedDates](
    [LockedDateID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsYearly] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.LockedDates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LockedDateID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters](
    [EmployeGroupFilterID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.EmployeGroupFilters] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeGroupFilterID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Project]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Project](
    [ProjectID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectTitle] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectDescription] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ScheduleID] [int] NULL,
    [EstimatedHours] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [IsRetired] [bit] NULL,
    [Color] [int] NULL,
    [PaymoID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Project] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProjectID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Cases]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cases](
    [CaseID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CaseTitle] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CaseDescription] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ScheduleID] [int] NULL,
    [EstimatedHours] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [StatusID] [int] NULL,
    [Color] [int] NULL,
    [CRMID] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Cases] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CaseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Task]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task](
    [TaskID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TaskTitle] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [TaskDescription] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] [int] NULL,
    [ScheduleID] [int] NULL,
    [PaymoID] [int] NULL,
    [ParentScheduleID] [int] NULL,
    [IsUnscheduelable] [bit] NULL,
    [EstimatedHours] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [PaymoUser] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [PaymoOrder] [int] NULL,
    [PaymoEstimateHours] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Task] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TaskID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Customer_Case]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Customer_Case] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([CustomerID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Customer_Case]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Case]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Case] FOREIGN KEY([ScheduleID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schedule] ([ScheduleID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Case]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Status_Case]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Status_Case] FOREIGN KEY([StatusID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Statuses] ([StatusID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Status_Case]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Group_Employee]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Group_Employee] FOREIGN KEY([GroupID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Group] ([GroupID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Group_Employee]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Employee_EmployeGroupFilter]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Employee_EmployeGroupFilter] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Employee_EmployeGroupFilter]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Group_EmployeGroupFilter]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Group_EmployeGroupFilter] FOREIGN KEY([GroupID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Group] ([GroupID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Group_EmployeGroupFilter]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Employee_LockedDate]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LockedDates]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Employee_LockedDate] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LockedDates] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Employee_LockedDate]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Project]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Project] FOREIGN KEY([ScheduleID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schedule] ([ScheduleID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Project]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Employee_Schedule]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Employee_Schedule] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Employee_Schedule]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Recurring_Schedule]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Recurring_Schedule] FOREIGN KEY([RecurringID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Recurring] ([RecurringID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Recurring_Schedule]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Project_Task]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Project_Task] FOREIGN KEY([ProjectID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Project] ([ProjectID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Project_Task]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Task]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task] FOREIGN KEY([ScheduleID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schedule] ([ScheduleID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Task1]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task1] FOREIGN KEY([ParentScheduleID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schedule] ([ScheduleID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task1]
GO
```

Comment: What is the content of the kb.sql file? SQL DDL statements?

Comment: create table, alter table, etc...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something completely, but why you don't launch SQL Server Management Studio and run that batch file? Or use the SQLCMD.exe command line utility? They must have given you access to the database with a well known management tool. BTW: Scripts like these should never be triggered by a page visit!

Comment: No, their web manager only lets me create tables 1 by 1...

Comment: Well, then I would change your hoster. Providing a database with no access to real management tools is ridiculous. How will you create backups? Monitor health?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunate the hoster doesn't offer better DB management tools, but maybe you can try using the `SqlCommand` class which can execute `DDL` statements. Unfortunately, you have to split the statements by the `GO` separator. In my example, I use regular expressions to do it, but it might fail depending on where the word "GO" is used in the script:

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=[server];Database=[database];Integrated Security=True"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
{
    cnn.Open();
    MatchCollection coll = Regex.Matches(script, @"(?<cmd>.+)\s*GO\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    foreach (Match m in coll)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = m.Groups["cmd"].Value;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```